# Intermittent Cannot locate resource exception when working with images

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I keep getting System.IO.Exceptions of cannot locate resource, This issue pops up every now and then when I write software and usually magically resolves itself after a couple builds, not this time though.

The Uri I am using to reference the image is:
`"pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Right_Stick.png"`

This fails even though right above it:
`"pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Left_Stick.png"`
passes.

I have both images in the same folder in my project and both set to the Resource build type, I also verified that the file names were correct, but one works perfectly and one throws an error every time.

The code throwing the error:

```
private Dictionary<string, InputChannel> _InputChannels = new Dictionary<string, InputChannel>(){
    {"LSX", new InputChannelTypes.JoyAxis(){ChannelName = "Left Stick X", max_Value=1000,min_Value=-1000,
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Left_Stick.png"))
    }},
    {"LSY", new InputChannelTypes.JoyAxis(){ChannelName = "Left Stick Y", max_Value=1000,min_Value=-1000,
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Left_Stick.png"))
    }},
    {"RSX", new InputChannelTypes.JoyAxis(){ChannelName = "Right Stick X", max_Value=1000,min_Value=-1000,
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Right_Stick.png"))
    }},
    {"RSY", new InputChannelTypes.JoyAxis(){ChannelName = "Right Stick Y", max_Value=1000,min_Value=-1000,
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Right_Stick.png"))
    }},

    {"LS", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "Left Stick",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Left_Stick.png"))
    }},
    {"RS", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "Right Stick",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Right_Stick.png"))
    }},

    {"LT", new InputChannelTypes.JoyAxis(){ChannelName = "Left Trigger", max_Value=1000,min_Value=0,
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_LT.png"))
    }},
    {"RT", new InputChannelTypes.JoyAxis(){ChannelName = "Right Trigger", max_Value=1000,min_Value=0,
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_RT.png"))
    }},
    {"LB", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "Left Bumper",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_LB.png"))
    }},
    {"RB", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "Right Bumper",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_RB.png"))
    }},

    {"DUp", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "DPad Up",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Dpad_Up.png"))
    }},
    {"DDown", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "DPad Down",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Dpad_Down.png"))
    }},
    {"DLeft", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "DPad Left",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Dpad_Left.png"))
    }},
    {"DRight", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "DPad Right",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Dpad_Right.png"))
    }},

    {"A", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "A",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_A.png"))
    }},
    {"B", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "B",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_B.png"))
    }},
    {"X", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "X",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_X.png"))
    }},
    {"Y", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "Y",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Y.png"))
    }},

    {"Start", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "Start",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Start.png"))
    }},
    {"Back", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "Back",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/360_Back.png"))
    }},
    {"Guide", new InputChannelTypes.Button(){ChannelName = "Guide",
        ChannelIcon=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/iX360;component/Resources/Xbox.ico"))
    }}
};
```

The exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot locate resource
>   'resources/360_right_stick.png'.

Ive also tried switching back and forth from Embeded Resource to Resource in the build types, no luck.

Update:
After a couple more builds today with no changes to the URI or file structure or build types, it now finds `360_Right_Stick.png` but is now hanging on `360_LT.png`. This is extremely peculiar.

Comment: The issue seems to have resolved after upgrading to VS 2015, leading me to believe it was a bug in the IDE itself.